# XPath query works on JS but not selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, xpath

I have this (see below) XPath query that does work just fine on Javascript but it hangs, certainly becuase it didn't find the element yet, so it's waiting for time out. How can I fix this?

```
var span = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text() = \"What's your name?\"]/ancestor::div[@class=\"office-form-question-content office-form-theme-focus-border\"]//input[@class=\"office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control border-no-radius\"]"));
```

where driver is of [`this`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebDriver.htm) type. The target peice of HTML look like this:

```
<div class="office-form-question-content office-form-theme-focus-border">
  <div aria-live="assertive" role="alert"></div>
  <div class="question-title-box">
    <div>
      <div aria-level="2" class="office-form-question-title" id="question1-title" role="heading"><span class="ordinal-number">1.</span><span>What's your name?</span><span class="required-star"></span>
        <div><span class="accessibility-reader-no-display" id="question1-required">Requer resposta</span></div>
        <div><span class="accessibility-reader-no-display" id="question1-questiontype">Texto de linha única</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="office-form-question-element">
    <div class="student-feedback-view-short-text-field-with-correctness">
      <div>
        <div class="office-form-textfield"><input class="office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control border-no-radius" aria-labelledby="question1-title question1-required question1-questiontype" placeholder="Insira sua resposta" spellcheck="true" maxlength="4000"
            value=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran it successfully using your xpath expression and HTML snippet.

```java
driver.get("file:///C:/demo.html");

String xpath = "//span[text() = \"What's your name?\"]/ancestor::div[@class=\"office-form-question-content office-form-theme-focus-border\"]//input[@class=\"office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control border-no-radius\"]";
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
e.sendKeys("quan");
```

my enviroment:

```
Chrome 84.0.4147.125
ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30
```

So, "XPath query does not work selenium" may not be the real reason.

Comment: that really works on that small local HTML code but not on online page, where I copy that literal piece of HTML. On the HTML page it returns: `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'Unable to locate element: //span[text() = "What's your name?"]/ancestor::div[@class="office-form-question-content office-form-theme-focus-border"]//input[@class="office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control border-no-radius"]'`